# Can a complete latex file be rendered on webpage using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, latex, mathjax, tex

Can a complete latex file be rendered on webpage using php or javascript?

I am not talking about just latex equations because I know that this can easily be done using MathJax. I mean can a complete `.tex` file with `\title`, `\abstract`, `\begin{}`, `\end{}` and other latex commands be rendered on webpage.

Basically, My site is a tex file editor. So people create latex files and store them in my database then they can edit them if they wish to. I am looking for a way so that my users can compile the tex file they stored in my database on the webpage itself not pdf.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rendered"? You could generate a pdf from the LaTeX source and then render that.

Comment: JavaScript is turing complete, of course it can do anything other languages can do computationally. But have any people create such libraries is the main problem.

Comment: I mean to generate the compile on to webpage not pdf.

Comment: Be aware that latex is made for print targets with a fixed page size. You are going to have issues with the layout of the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this: http://phplatex.scarfboy.com/
You can download the code from [github](https://github.com/scarfboy/phplatex).

If you're a Symfony user you can use [this latex package](https://github.com/bobvandevijver/latex-bundle). This package can generate pdf and tex files from HTML. Is not exactly what you want. Probably this can inspire you.

Both are not tested by my but I hope it helps you!